# Hashmap in Java having "[" "]" these symbols

Tags: java

I am iterating over hashmap, but these strange brackets [ ] are there while iterating, Can any body guide me how can i get rid of it.

Thanks

```
 Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();                 
                System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());                      
                Log.v("Pairs get key", pairs.getKey().toString());
                Log.v("Pairs get value", pairs.getValue().toString());
                mysection.add(pairs.getKey().toString());
                temp.add(pairs.getValue().toString());

                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, you haven't provided enough detail.  A code sample and sample output would be helpful.

Comment: Could you post the code which you are using? A hashmap has brackets enclosing it when converted into a string.

Comment: some context for the brackets would greatly help. Please paste the line which contains these brackets

Comment: Any chance one of the values (I hope not one of the keys) is an array?

Comment: I don't see any square brackets here.

Comment: @AztecCoder Well then it would make sense to show us a few lines of the log where they appear, wouldn't it?

Comment: We need to see log output showing the brackets, but based on the code: do you know what the type of the key and value in a given Map.Entry is?  The toString() method of the types involved might be generating Strings that include the brackets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i got the answer, the problem was map when displayed into console will show , and [] symbol. So to avoid it use another implementation to iterate over map and not this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to gloss over the part where the code doesn't use generics and where you don't actually give us the "unexpected" output so that we can's figure out what the problem is, really, and list the three situations where you can get "these strange symbols":

1. The keys or values of the map are some type of collection. Then the collection's `toString` method will print its contents, e.g. `[1]`, or `[1,2,3]`.
2. The keys or values of the map are an array of something. Then `Object`'s `toString` method will print the object type and address, e.g. `[Ljava.lang.String;@19821f` is an array of strings.
3. The keys or values of the map are `String`s with `[]`s in them, or some other type of object whose `toString` method prints `[]`s.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code.

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("AAAA", "11111");
    map.put("BBBB", "22222");
    map.put("CCCC", "33333");

    Iterator<Entry<String,String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();                 
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());                      
        System.out.println("Pairs get key: "+pairs.getKey().toString());
        System.out.println("Pairs get value: "+pairs.getValue().toString());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
```

Output was

```
AAAA = 11111
Pairs get key: AAAA
Pairs get value: 11111
BBBB = 22222
Pairs get key: BBBB
Pairs get value: 22222
CCCC = 33333
Pairs get key: CCCC
Pairs get value: 33333
```

Only difference was that I  have no idea what data you are putting in the map. IF you put a List it will output with [] symbols because java will be printing its toString() method and that's how lists show.